# jquery nth-child append (first and second dd in dl) trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to select the 1st/2nd dd in a dl, to add a  to them

HTML:

```
<dl> <dt></dt> 
    <p></p>
    <dd></dd>
    <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

JS(Jquery):

```
$("dl dd:nth-child(1)").after("<sub>md</sub>");
 $("dl dd:nth-child(2)").after("<sub>lg</sub>");
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dv0L063/1/)

How can I accomplish for more than one dl? Would I have to use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `nth-of-type` and it will add it to all (your fiddle was also not running jquery)

```
$("dl dd:nth-of-type(1)").after("<sub>md</sub>");
$("dl dd:nth-of-type(2)").after("<sub>lg</sub>");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0dv0L063/2/)

Comment: MANY THANKS!!btw used .append (.after broke my code) ;)